# How can i make toggle shortcuts like org mode or magit

Tags: org-mode, magit, hydra

I am writing an elisp package currently I am using hydra, I would like to be able to have shortcuts you can toggle on and off for various flags.

You see this sort of thing in magit and org mode when you press the key and it hightlight the text another colour to indicate the flag is checked before selecting an actual option.

What are my options and can hydra do this sort of thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether Hydra supports this (like you I would have to look at the documentation to be sure). I think it only supports setting the value of lisp variables, but not arguments to commands.

Magit's popup functionality is available as a separate package `magit-popup`. It comes with [a manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup).

Comment: I did look at the docs and could not find anything, but sometimes the terminology is different to expected good to know about magit-popup I may look into that as an alternative. Thanks for the link